# Arrows inside a table, marking transition between table cells

Tags: tables

Is it possible to have arrows showing transition between cells inside a table?
I doubt I could do this just by using tables, so I was wondering if there was someway to get something like that working.

Eg:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Relations between cells can be visualize very comfortable with the package (bundle) `tikz`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel will it be able to do something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/ebUzr.png ?

Comment: Yes it can. This is every simple and I am sure we have similar question somewhere.

Comment: The following are useful (duplicates): [Arrows between two tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60897/5764); [Tabular with arrows or lines between some cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68127/5764); [Drawing Arrows in Tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37738/5764); [Drawing Multiple Diagonal Arrows in a Table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38169/5764); [Adding lines that go from one cell to another on a different row](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32441/5764); [TikZ: how to draw chained tabular material](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59286/5764).

Comment: @Werner I found the second one best suited to my needs. Thanks again for the help!